# Why can one pour water on a car battery's terminals (12 Vdc) and not have shorting

Tags: automotive, short-circuit, batteries

When cleaning a standard 12 Vdc car battery's terminals, it's a common practice to pour a mixture of baking soda + hot water all over the terminals.  The water can spread and effectively short out the battery in two ways:

- Positive terminal to negative terminal
- Positive terminal to car chassis (to negative terminal)

Why does this not cause major problems (ex: explosions)?

---

**Background**

Quora answer: [What happens if a car battery short circuits?](https://qr.ae/pNrMRB)

YouTube video: [Shorting Out a 12V Car Battery](https://youtu.be/ZfFViY1-zYw)

Indicates that shorting a car's battery can be quite detrimental.

YouTube video: [How to clean car battery terminals corrosion Cheap and EASY with baking soda Car maintenance](https://youtu.be/7tH3vCEyNk0?t=66)

You can see the water connects the battery's positive terminal to the negative terminal.  In my mind, this should create a short circuit, as the water is effectively shorting the positive and negative terminals.  However, nothing bad seems to happen.  Why is this?

---

**Research**

Reddit post: [ELI5: Why is it safe to pour water all over a car battery?](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1k64ll/eli5_why_is_it_safe_to_pour_water_all_over_a_car/)

Says water isn't all that conductive, but I am not sure if I agree with this vague statement.

Comment: *"Says water isn't all that conductive, but I am not sure if I agree with this vague statement"* For all it vagueness, the statement is more or less right if you talk about 12V.

Comment: Hi! Nice to have you here from your intrastellar exploration! General note: Youtube videos are definitely not a reliable source, and if I had a nickel for every time someone came on here and said "in this youtube video they saidy X, so why X?" and then everyone here was "oooh, X? that's totally wrong!", I would have enough nickels for a while!

Comment: @Oldfart you can certainly get into to the single-digit ohm region with 20cm of water bridge saturated with baking soda.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was talking of normal water. I did not wanted to digress but was thinking  to add that a film of conducting water (e.g. very salty) was likely to evaporate quickly with 20A going through it.

Comment: yeah, at the point where the current becomes problematic for the battery or bystanders, the water will be gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition of short circuit – according to IEC – is accidental or intentional conductive path between two or more conductive parts forcing the electric potential differences between these **conductive parts to be equal to or close to zero**.

You can short the battery with a wrench or copper wire, but not with water. Tap water is so poor conductor ([about couple of tens of millisiemens/meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_(electrolytic))) that it does not cause a short circuit, only a little electrolysis bubbling (or corrosion if the terminals are wet a long time).

Comment: My question in the comment above was: what should we call an unintended current flow in a circuit? Based on the definition of a short that you cited above, it is unclear to me how to describe the current that flows through the water, other than perhaps, leakage current. What is the problem with describing all unintended current paths as shorts?

Comment: @Qubit1028 The problem is, that they have different definitions. Short circuit is defined "accidental or intentional conductive path between two or more conductive parts forcing the electric potential differences between these conductive parts to be equal to or close to zero"

Leakage current is defined "electric current in an unwanted conductive path other than a short circuit".

So, because the current is so low that the potential between terminals is not zero, this is a leakage current. Always check the IEC definitions first :).

Comment: For clarification purposes, assume that a very thin copper wire is connected between the battery terminals that has a sufficiently high resistance to only drop the voltage by about 10%. Now, this does not meet the strict definition of a short, but it seems reasonable to actually call it a short, at least to me it does. The 10% reduction in voltage due to the unintended current through the copper wire could cause the designed circuit to behave improperly. We need a way to describe a situation like this. If we don't call it a short, what do we call it?

Comment: ... and I think the "short" term means the current is taking an easy "short-cut" home and deviating from the approved path.

Comment: @Qubit1028 Connecting battery terminals with very thin copper wire to form a short that droops the battery voltage by 10% is impossible. As the car battery is a 12V source with low enough internal resistance to give out say 300 amps, any thin copper wire would vaporize in microseconds. It would require several amps, if not tens of amps to bring down the voltage by 10%, so it would not be a thin wire, and loads of only tens of amps are common loads for the battery so it would not be considered a short but normal loading.

Comment: tell it to all the people who ruined electric devices when they were exposed to water.

Answer (score 4):

Shorting means connecting with something that conducts electricity well.

Water does not conduct much. So it does not short it.

(At least in the context of it being a 12V battery)

Comment: It does short in the technical sense of the word. Current will flow via electrolysis of the water/cleaning solution. The combination of two factors keeps the short current very low: 1) low conductivity, as you pointed out and 2) low electrode surface area.

Comment: Shorts as much as a 1 megaohm resistor. I would not call it a short, even if in the technical sense it connects the terminals. But plastic, dirt and air connect the terminals too, so technically they would be shorting the terminals too then?

Comment: @Qubit1028 No, it is not a *short* in the technical sense of the word. A short circuit is a **very low** resistance connection.

Comment: @Elliot I think this may be a matter of semantics. Definition of a short is current flow through a resistance that is lower than the normal circuit. In this case, I assume the battery is at open-circuit so any current flowing through the water may be thought of as a short. Here is a question though: how should we describe a current of any value that is unintended in a circuit? Would you call that leakage current rather than a short?

Comment: Let's stop arguing and see the IEC definitions:

* Short circuit = "accidental or intentional conductive path between two or more conductive parts forcing the electric potential differences between these conductive parts to be equal to or close to zero"

* Leakage current = "electric current in an unwanted conductive path other than a short circuit".

Comment: Kiitos Vesa. My thoughts exactly. Water, or water saturated with baking soda, does not short cirtcuit.